# How to render updated state in react Js?

Tags: reactjs

I am working on React Js in class component I am declaring some states and then getting data from API and changing that state to new value but React is not rendering that new value of state. but if I console.log() that state it gives me new value on console.

**My code**

```
class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      unread: 0,
    }
    this.getUnread()
  }
  getUnread = async () => {
    let data = await Chatapi.get(`count/${this.props.auth.user.id}/`).then(({ data }) => data);
    this.setState({ unread: data.count });
    console.log(this.state.unread)
  }
  render() {
    const { auth } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.unread}
      </div>
    )
  }
```

This is printing 2 on console but rendering 0 on screen. How can I get updated state(2) to render on screen.

and if I visit another page and then return to this page then it is rendering new value of state (2).

Answer (score 0):

Please call getUnread() function in componentDidMount, something like this

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.getUnread()
}
```

Comment: still working same as above

Comment: can you please update state like this:

this.setState((state, props) => {
  return {unread:data.count};
}); 

and please also console.log on render method

Answer (score 0):

This is because in React class components, while calling `setState` you it is safer to not directly pass a value to set the state (and hence, re-render the component). This is because what happens that the state is set as commanded, but when the component is rerendered, once again the state is set back to initial value and that is what gets rendered

You can read this issue and its solution as given in [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html)

You pass a function that sets the value.

So, code for setState would be

```
 this.setState((state) => { unread: data.count });
```

Hence, your updated code would be :

```
class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      unread: 0,
    }
    this.getUnread()
  }
  getUnread = async () => {
    let data = await Chatapi.get(`count/${this.props.auth.user.id}/`).then(({ data }) => data);
    this.setState((state) => { unread: data.count });
    console.log(this.state.unread)
  }
  render() {
    const { auth } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.unread}
      </div>
    )
  }
```